# Colon Expected Error In Visual Studio Code (VSC)

Tags: json

im having trouble with this code. Its very simple but i dont seem to get whats wrong with it.

```
{
  "type":"web",
  "file":"Index.html",
  "description"
  "general": {
  "supportaudioprocessing": "true"
}
```

> Colon Expected (5,1)
>
> Colon Expected (7,1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every item needs a key-value pair and close all brackets:

```
{
  "type":"web",
  "file":"Index.html",
  "description": "**NEED A VALUE FOR THIS KEY**"
  "general": {
     "supportaudioprocessing": "true"
  }
}
```